# Selecting in between won't work with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quick and asap issue.

```
SELECT `deals`.*
  FROM `deals`
  WHERE
    `is_featured` = 1 AND
    `status` = 'active' AND
    CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Is this right?

`start_date` is "2012-01-11 00:00:00" and `end_date` is "2012-01-11 23:59:59".

This is what I wish to show:

I want to show the dealoffer that is between the current datetime and if the `is_featured` is 1 and `status` are "active".

(`CURDATE()` gives me only date, not time, is this the problem? How can I get current datetime in MySql?).

It should only pick one deal and this deal should be the one with the closest end date from current datetime.

Comment: Are there any deals with future dates? If not, perhaps you could find the one with max date instead? Or if there are future dates, could you look for max date that is less than current date?

Comment: That should work. What error do you get? BTW, NOW() will return a current datetime for you.

Comment: What datatype are start_date and end_date?

Comment: btw - a date will be expanded to date 00:00:00 ie.. 2012-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT `deals`.* FROM `deals`
WHERE `is_featured` = 1
AND `status` = 'active'
AND CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Replace the BETWEEN with this

```
SELECT `deals`.* FROM `deals`
WHERE `is_featured` = 1
AND `status` = 'active'
AND start_date >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
AND start_date <= (end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

and add this index

```
ALTER TABLE deals ADD INDEX (is_featured,status,start_date,end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `now()` to get the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the curtime() function to retrieve the current time.